# Planet order in solar system

Tags: planets, solar-system

Why does Mars not follow the logical planet order in space? From small rocky planets to big ones and from big gas planets to small ones?

Comment: Who told you that such a "logical order" has to exist in mature planetary systems? For one thing, planets can wander far away from their original orbits during and long after their genesis in the protostellar disk. How much material a planet can accrete during that phase also depends on the details of the very early system, so it's not clear why mass should increase in a certain way. If we are learning anything from exoplanet searches, it's the incredible diversity of systems that these processes result in.

Comment: Note the Uranus is lighter than Neptune. There is no neat and satisfying pattern and no particular reason to expect one.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is based on an unbased preconception, which simply turns out to be false.

Comment: Please don't close. I'm working on an answer. This is the "small Mars problem".

Comment: I agree there is *something* here. Often properties of protoplanetary disks (surface density, dynamical timescale, etc.) change monotonically with radius, so one might expect planet properties to do the same except across qualitative changes (e.g. the ice line delineating the inner and outer solar system). The Uranus/Neptune inversion is partly why some support the [Nice model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nice_model).

Answer (score 4):

Rev 2: Partially finished, but now I have Saturday chores to do. I'll  finish filling in this outline later this evening.

---

A number of planetary formation simulations from late in the 20th century to early in the 21st century suggested that Mars should be at most a bit smaller than Venus or Earth. This obviously is not the case. Explaining this is the "small Mars problem". More recent works offer explanations (but not yet complete and fully accepted answers) toward this problem. This answer focuses on several key papers that led to a fairly recent hypothesis that provides an answer to the "small Mars problem."

**Jumpin' Jupiter! (exoplanets)** (Weidenschilling, 1996) and (Marzari, 2002)
Many of the first discovered exoplanets did not fit within the nice, clean planetary formation models that had been developed in the 20th century. Instead of gas giants of finding gas giants orbiting circularly at five to fifteen AU, scientists found hot jupiters and jupiters with very high eccentricities. This didn't make sense.

Marzari hypothesized a cause as chaotic behavior amongst multiple gas giants, followed by close-by interactions amongst the planets. The result was at least one giant expelled from the planetary system during the process, and another jumping to a much closer orbit than that at which the planet formed.

**Nice Model** (Multiple papers, 2005 and later)
The Nice Model is an evolving framework that initially described problems with the late stage of the formation of the solar system. Nepture and Uranus are particularly problematic. They are too far from the Sun to have formed where they are, and their masses are inverted. I'll address later developments / offshoots of the Nice model below.

**Mars Formed Fast** (Qin, 2008)
A small number of meteorites found on Earth originated from Mars. These Mars meteorites yield evidence of how quickly Mars formed, and apparently it was very quick indeed. Mars reached half it's current size in less than 2 million years. Compare that with the 50 to 100 million years estimated for the formation of the Earth.

This suggests that Mars went through the first four phases of terrestrial planet formation (dust accumulation, followed by protoplanet formation, followed by runaway growth, followed by oligarchic growth) but somehow missed out on the final mopping up phase where planetary embryos collide to finally form a planet. Why? The article doesn't say.

**Jumpin' Jupiter! (our Jupiter)** (Morbidelli, 2009) and (Brasser, 2009)

**Fifth Gas Giant?** (Nesvorný, 2011)

**Grand Tack Model** (Walsh, 2011)
Walsh et al. provides an explanation to why Mars formed so quickly. Per their Grand Tack hypothesis, Saturn jumped inward shortly after its initial formation, and this in turn forced to migrate into the inner solar system. This inward migration stopped when reached about 1.5 AU of the Sun. Jupiter and Saturn then began migrating outward, but the damage was done. This inward migration swept the region between 1.0 and 1.5 AU clear of dust. There was no dust from which Mars could form. Instead, Mars formed from stuff expelled as the Earth formed.

**References**

[Brasser, R., et al. "Constructing the secular architecture of the solar system II: the terrestrial planets." *Astronomy and Astrophysics* 507 (2009): 1053-1065.](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0909.1891v1.pdf)

[Marzari, F., and S. J. Weidenschilling. "Eccentric extrasolar planets: the jumping Jupiter model." *Icarus* 156.2 (2002): 570-579.](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0019103501967867)

[Morbidelli, A., et al. "Constructing the secular architecture of the solar system I: The giant planets." *Astronomy and Astrophysics* 507.2 (2009): 1041.](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0909.1886v1.pdf)

[Nesvorný, David. "Young solar system's fifth giant planet?" *Astrophysical Journal Letters* 742.2 (2011): L22.](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1109.2949v1.pdf)

[Qin, Liping, et al. "Rapid accretion and differentiation of iron meteorite parent bodies inferred from <sup>182</sup>Hf–<sup>182</sup>W chronometry and thermal modeling." *Earth and Planetary Science Letters* 273.1 (2008): 94-104.](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012821X08003877)

[Stolte, Andrea, "Planet formation." *Star Formation Lecture Series* (2012)](http://www.astro.uni-bonn.de/~astolte/StarFormation/Lecture2012_Planets.pdf)

[Walsh, Kevin J., et al. "A low mass for Mars from Jupiter's early gas-driven migration." Nature 475.7355 (2011): 206-209.](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.5177.pdf)

[Weidenschilling, Stuart J., and Francesco Marzari. "Gravitational scattering as a possible origin for giant planets at small stellar distances." *Nature* 384.6610 (1996): 619-621.](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v384/n6610/abs/384619a0.html)

Comment: It is interesting to see how much thought people have put into this... but given the exoplanet statistics doesn't it looks a little bit like early models were over-fitting to the only known example? Hindsight is 20/20, so I don't blame the researchers of the past. I suppose we don't have a three parameter model of planet formation that can account for the real statistics of observations? Maybe the evidence suggests, that such a model can't even exist?

Comment: A three parameter model? Good gosh, no. That is far too spherical a cow. By the late 1980s, astrophysicists thought they had a fairly complete semi-analytic model of planetary formation. Computers were just starting to get powerful enough to be able to simulate planetary formation, and since Moore's law was in full swing, they expected those simulations to soon confirm their formation models. Astronomy was getting better and better; they also expected to see exoplanets that confirmed their formation models. Oops! Some funny things happened on the way to the 21st century.

Comment: If Jupiter moved in to about 1.5 AU, and then moved out again, where did Jupiter get the energy to move outward?

Comment: Who doesn't like spherical cows that are isotropically covered in milk? :-) To be honest with you, I think that the curve ball of exoplanet observations is one of the best things that happened to science in a long time. Like I said, I don't blame the folks who worked so hard for a century to make these beautiful models... and I admire nature for destroying them so completely.

Comment: @LDC3: The critical question is, where did the angular momentum come from?

Comment: @LDC3 - Inspiraling dust. This migration happened early on in the formation of the solar system. The direction in which the migration of giant planets proceeds depends on whether the density gradient of the dust is directed toward the Sun (in which case migration is sunward) or against the Sun (in which case migration is outward). Jupiter had just cleared the region between 1.0 and 1.5 AU of dust. The only dust present was that that was inspiraling from outer regions of the solar system, so the migration was outward.

Comment: @CuriousOne - It didn't destroy them completely. The basic concepts developed up until near the end of 20th century still remain. How planets form? That's still more or less unchanged. That planets migrated? That too is more or less unchanged. That bodies interact gravitationally? That's a 300 year old idea. These ideas just needed some refinements.

Comment: @DavidHammen: The main problem is that planet migration can be a chaotic process if more than one gas giant is involved. Even with Monte Carlo simulations that's a hard to control business. Current orbits are not good evidence for the early history of the system. I think we can probably piece it together with chemical samples from all over the system... but that's probably a century worth of deep space flight ahead of us. On the other hand... that's one exciting science mystery!